# Auto break line in HTML

Tags: html, css

I've been doing a comment box and I have a problem after viewing my comment. All I want is to make my comment auto break line when it exceeds the container but what I've got right now is a straight line.

For example:

```
tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt
```

I hope my text can be like this:

```
ttttttttttttt
ttttttttttttt 
ttttttttttttt 
ttttttttttttt
```

What should I use to make my text auto break line?

Answer (score 47):

It sounds like you're after `word-wrap: break-word`, and its cross-browser variants.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/white-space

```
selector {
      word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE 5.5-7 */
      white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox 1.0-2.0 */
      white-space: pre-wrap;      /* current browsers */
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MCj6s/

Comment: `word-wrap: break-word;` is the current one. `white-space: pre-wrap;` is instead for something different! It preserves all whitespaces and linebreaks are ONLY done at `\n` (a linebreak in the source),`<br>` and as necessary to fill line boxes. It does not cause wrapping inside words.

Answer (score 2):

Try using string replacement:

```
$line_broken = str_replace("\n", "<br />", $comment);
```

But it's hard to tell without seeing your code.

Comment: I think he wants long strings to break to new lines automatically, but I might have misunderstood...

Comment: I don't think this is the issue, but if it is, there's a native function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Answer (score 1):

A solution using HTML: The tag `<wbr>` marks a "suggested word break", aka a position inside a word where it is ok to do a linebreak.

`MySuperLongWord` would not have linebreaks by default.
`My<wbr>Super<wbr>Long<wbr>Word` would have linebreaks at `<wbr>` where necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to auto-break your line without a chunk of PHP. You could consider using the CSS `overflow: hidden;` or `overflow: auto;` for your comment container.

Comment: i tried overflow but still not working. thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

use `<br>` where you want it to linebreak

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers.