# Is there any way to wrap html text when 'all one word' is used?

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to word-wrap text in a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638223/is-there-a-way-to-word-wrap-text-in-a-div)

I have this css and html issue. I have a description and I want to fit it in a box that is 100px wide and I want the text to flow down the page. I have set up a div like thisL:

```
<div style="width:100px; border:1px Solid Black; height:200px; overflow:scroll; "><p>text here...</p></div>
```

However when I put text in and there is no white space the text does not wrap. So if a user was to put in one word that spanned more than 100px wide then the text will flow off to the right which I dont want....

Any way to stop this? I noticed facebook wall posts dont do this behaviour....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most straight forward way is to use `word-wrap: break-word`

[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/9SQTh/)

Comment: cheers :-) this worked a treat

Answer (score 0):

1. CSS solution :
   use overflow:hidden   and overflow-x:hidden
2. Backend solution:
   if you are using a scripting language like php to generate your page,
   use "word wrap" technique to break the long word data.

Comment: This will hide the overflow, but will not break it.

Comment: agreeed. word-wrap: break-word   does not work in IE6 I suppose. so hidden seemed a better option. http://www.brunildo.org/test/IEbreak-word.html

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322929/word-wrap-in-css-js).

`word-wrap : break-word` is the most compatible way going forward, but will not help in some browsers that are still widely used.

Answer (score 0):

change `height` to `min-height` and remove `overflow` and use `word-wrap: break-word` :

```
<div style="width:100px; border:1px Solid Black; min-height:200px;word-wrap: break-word; "><p>text here...</p></div>
```

but remember if user does not type any space, no browser will break it to multiple lines!

Comment: `"if user does not type any space, no browser will break it to multiple lines"` ..unless you use `word-wrap: break-word`. See a recent answer of mine that includes a demo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852700/help-in-auto-break-line/5852740#5852740