# Wrap a long single word using CSS

Tags: html, css

I tried to wrap a single word which contains around 500+ chars in a div.

```
<table><tr><td style="width: 100px;" colspan=""><div class="wordwrap"><p>
dwhjifuidfinrnvfrvgjsrfjoejwofjjfpijqfpqejospjfcjcdefjipwejpfjespfjweokpwoefweeeepWSPgjwrqeo[fj[ejwo[jfqjfo[cfj[e[awfjw[fw[ofj[sejfpjwerpjfpwrjgjrjghyhefdjsjflkfasjgfiosdjfgsfgsdfiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiigrwewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewettttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttu
</p></div> </td></tr></table>
```

with this solution provided In [Is there a way to word-wrap long words in a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638223/is-there-a-way-to-word-wrap-text-in-a-div)

```
<style type="text/css">
 .wordwrap { 
   white-space: pre-wrap;      /* CSS3 */   
   white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */    
   white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera <7 */   
   white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */    
   word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE */
}
 </style>
```

But it is not working. 
Followed this [Is there any way to wrap html text when 'all one word' is used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866961/is-there-any-way-to-wrap-html-text-when-all-one-word-is-used) also . 
What could be the problem?

Comment: Just add display:table; in your class.

Comment: If you remove the table around it, it works for me.

Answer (score 26):

Because your long word is within a `<table>` - you need to add `table-layout: fixed;`

```
table { 
   width: 100%; 
   word-wrap:break-word;
   table-layout: fixed;
}
```

```css
table { 
   width: 100%; 
   word-wrap:break-word;
   table-layout: fixed;
}
```

```html
<table ><tr><td style="width: 100px;" colspan=""><div class="wordwrap"><p>
dwhjifuidfinrnvfrvgjsrfjoejwofjjfpijqfpqejospjfcjcdefjipwejpfjespfjweokpwoefweeeepWSPgjwrqeo[fj[ejwo[jfqjfo[cfj[e[awfjw[fw[ofj[sejfpjwerpjfpwrjgjrjghyhefdjsjflkfasjgfiosdjfgsfgsdfiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiigrwewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewewettttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttu

</p></div> </td></tr></table>
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/sbu6K/)**

### Explanation:

The default value for `table-layout` is `auto` which means that the browser will decide the width of a column based on the content of the table cells.

In this case, the table layout algorithm will look at that really long word and say: 'heck, i'll need a really wide column to fit that word in'

By setting `table-layout` to `fixed` - The browser determines the width of the columns based on the width of the cells in the **first row** without taking into account the amount of content present in other rows.  (See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout#Values))

Here, there is one row with one cell - so `table-layout: fixed` says: make that cell the width of the entire table!  (was has `width: 100%`)

**NB:** For `table-layout: fixed` to take effect, the width of the table must be set (with a value other than `auto`)

For more details about `table-layout` - See [this article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/table-layout/)

Answer (score 8):

`word-wrap: break-word` should give you the result you’re after.

Answer (score 8):

Here is the code you should use:

```css
.wrapword {
  width: 200px;
  -ms-word-break: break-all;
  word-break: break-all;
  white-space: pre-wrap
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapword">
  dswfugfugfugfugfugfugfugfugfugfugfugfugfugfugfugfugfugfugfugfugfugfugfugfugfugfugfugfugfugfugfugfugfugfugfugfugfugfugfugfug
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You've also got HTML5's `<wbr>` tag: http://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/html_wbr_tag.cfm which lets you specify suitable break points

```
dwhjifuidfinrnvfrvgjsrfjoejwofjjfpijqfpqej<wbr>ospjfcjcdefjipwejpfjespfjweokpwoefweeeepWSPgjwrqeo
```

It might not be what you want, but it's worth playing around with

Answer (score 1):

There is property in css:

```
.selector {
    word-wrap: normal|break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add some `overflow` - `hidden`, `scroll`, `auto` ...

```
 .wordwrap { 
   white-space: pre-wrap;      /* CSS3 */   
   white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */    
   white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera <7 */   
   white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */    
   word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE */
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

Also your Followed answer contains `oveflow: scroll;`

Answer (score -2):

Try this. It worked for me.

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <div style="width:200px;">
    <span style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed;word-wrap:break-word;display:inline-table">
      hadfskldfjsdjlfjlsdkflkdsfsdrfsdfsdfsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsd
    </span>
  <div>
</body>
</html>
```