# How to Wrap a Label in WebForms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a label in my Webform. I want to wrap its text, so that it will automatically linebreak after a particular width in pixels.

The text for the label is coming from the database

```
        Label lblU = new Label();
       lblU.ID = "LabelU" + i.ToString();
        lblU.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString() + " : ";
```

There's no property like Autoresize or MaximumWidth, do I need some assembly references or something?

[image: this is the Bug I want to overcome]

Comment: Try `lblU.Width = Unit.Pixel(100)`. Webforms is HTML, a label will generate a `<span>`

Comment: Yes it is generating the span, I tried with your code but no success,

Comment: I update my question with image , please have a look sir @codingbiz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Label control renders as a `<span>` element, so just set its width via a style sheet:

I see that your example text has no white space. In that case, you have to set the word-wrap property to [break-word](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5866996/1036274)

```
span {width:5em; word-wrap:break-word}
```